# HTML Scraping using Html Agility Pack

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I have an HTML which contains the following code

```
<div id="image_src" style="display: block; "> 
<img id="captcha_img" src="" alt="image" onclick="imageClick(event)" style="cursor:crosshair;">
```

In this how can i detect the src using HTML Agility Pack ?

From another question I tried using the following LINQ

```
var urls = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("img")
                            .Select(e => e.GetAttributeValue("src", null))
                            .Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s));
```

but i keep getting null pointer exception here ...

I have only one image tag in entire HTML given like above

Can somebody help me please ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the HTML Agility Pack

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

string imgValue = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//img[@id = \"captcha_img\"]").GetAttributeValue("src", "0");
```

Answer (score 2):

To troubleshoot the null pointer exception, break each Linq statement into its own line, like this:

```
 var img = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("img");
 var s = img.Select(e => e.GetAttributeValue("src", null));
 var w = s.Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s));
```

Then, step through each line with the debugger, and see where it throws.